# Rails erb vs gsub dynamic template performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, gsub

In my project, I am using the ERB as template engine. We have one page which used ERB template and it's loaded within 5-7 seconds.

The same page we changed it into dynamic template, the template values are stored in the database.

sample template

```
    <p> {{name}} </p>
    <p> {{address}} </p>
    <p> {{mobile number}} </p>
```

For applying the actual values over dynamic template, i have used the gsub. This case the same page takes load time as 16-20 seconds. I used 17 gsub over dynamic template.

1. How erb rendering is fast? (Because i am using the same content
   before and after dynamic template)
2. Is there any way to increase the performance?

Note:
Compared to 'gsub' method, 'sub' method is fast. But in my case i need to use global sub (gsub).

Comment: We cannot determine the performance difference between the two without having one of them.

Comment: 2. Maybe you should have tried caching before you tried to reinvent the wheel? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the whole page is like a dynamic template with 20 tags. In that case gsub is not a correct solution to replace the 20 tags.

**Client Side:**
I have used the client side template engine called Handlebar.js. Using this my page loads with normal speed.

**Server Side:**
https://github.com/Shopify/liquid

Answer (score 0):

If you store templates in database then you could use appropriate tools to render them. If it's erb then just use [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), don't gsub variables manually. The reason why erb is so much faster than manual gsub is because erb template gets compiled to ruby code (like "Foo <%= bar %>" becomes "Foo " + bar) and executed.

As I understand you want to store your templates in database and render them both on server and client. You can use [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) for that, it's framework-agnostic and safe to run on server.